# No idea why I am getting Over Quota errors on GAE (Java)

Tags: quota, google-app-engine

I am getting over quota errors on my live GAE Standard Environment (Java) site and there's no information given on what has gone over quota.

I checked the [Quota Details](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails) page under App Engine, and everything seems ok.

I also looked at [IAM Admin quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) and everything is well within quotas there as well.

The logs show no message other than "Process terminated due to exceeding quotas." (which is of little help).

I guessed that maybe the daily spending quota was exhausted, so I increased that and it still isn't working. What's up?

If GAE knows enough to know I am over quota on something, why doesn't it send an email message to the admin to let him/her know which quota has exceeded the limit? Please consider this last bit an urgent feature request if any GAE support people see this.

PS: Is Server Fault the better place for asking about such issues or Stack Overflow?

#### Update 1:

A few minutes after increasing the daily spending limit the app started working again, so that must have been the issue. Still, shouldn't I have gotten an email to make me aware of this issue rather than hearing it from my users?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature that has been requested many times, and our engineering team has been working very hard on implementing a system that will alert users of their quota usage for all available resources in their projects. There are a lot of moving parts to this and so there is currently no ETA.

You can star the [public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/38167345) for this to receive a notification when it has been implemented. In the future, the correct place to report Google-end issues and feature requests is the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

---

[Currently you are able to create an alert](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293540?hl=en) if your expenses are about to reach your set budget. This can help in the prevention of exceeding your set spending limit so that you do not encounter this type of quota error again.